# Not able to extract regex matches, return "1" instead of string

Tags: regex, perl

I am seeing strange problem..can someplease please help.
I have a log template that looks like this

```
            CPU load:    0
            Memory load: 7
            User load:   0
            Interface Information:
              eth0: Up
              eth1: Up
            Processes Information:
```

Now, I login to my device and get the logs like 
my @output = $ssh->exec("show details");
The output looks similar, as show below but different values for parameters

```
            CPU load:    21
            Memory load: 27
            User load:   21
            Interface Information:
              eth0: Down
              eth1: Up
            Processes Information:
```

First I am opening the template file, split it into line by line and when I try to 
compate it with "show details" output, for the matches, I am getting value 1 as result
and not the matched string.  Can someone please help.

Code:

```
my @output = $ssh->exec("show details");
open (FH, "templates/SHOW.txt") || die "Could not open File: $!\n";
@file_array = <FH>;
@TemplateArray = split(/\n/,@file_array);
@matches = split(/\n/,@output);
foreach $keys (@matches) {
   foreach (@TemplateArray) {
     $keys =~ m/($_)/;
     unshift (@result_array, $1);
   }
}
print "\n @result_array\n";
```

}

I get "1" as result but no string.

Comment: what are you trying to do? I guess that you want to compare the output of `$ssh->exec("show details")` with the content of the template file, and that you want to return all lines that are different? Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `split` on an array, the array will be in scalar context, and will only return the number of elements in it. In other words:

```
@TemplateArray = split(/\n/,@file_array);
@matches = split(/\n/,@output);
```

is equal to:

```
@TemplateArray = $#file_array;
@matches       = $#output;
```

Which is why you get "1" as a result.

Also, if you are not already doing it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Comment: `$#file_array` -> `$#file_array+1`, `$#output` -> `$#output+1`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to TLP's answer, the solution is to change

```
@matches = split(/\n/,@output);
```

to

```
@matches = map { split(/\n/, $_) } @output;
```

so `split()` operates on strings from `@output`.

Comment: Actually, unless `$/` was changed, such a split would be kind of pointless, because each value in the array would end with a `\n`, and `\n` would never be found anywhere but at the end of a line.

Comment: @TLP thanks. In this case and context you are right; the code can be simplified to `@matches = chomp(@output);`. My original line of code seperates also multi-line strings. It was intended to show a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

`split`'s expects a string for its second argument, so

```
@TemplateArray = split(/\n/, @file_array);
```

ends up being the same as

```
@TemplateArray = split(/\n/, scalar(@file_array));
```

Keep in mind that `scalar(@file_array)` returns the number of elements in the array.

---

```
@file_array = <FH>;
```

will populate `@file_array` as follows:

```
@file_array = (
    "line1\n",
    "line2\n",
    "line3\n",
);
```

In other words, it's already split into lines. If you're trying to remove the trailing newlines, you want to replace

```
@TemplateArray = split(/\n/,@file_array);
```

with

```
chomp( my @TemplateArray = @file_array );
```

---

I can't help you fix

```
@matches = split(/\n/,@output);
```

because I don't know what `$ssh` contains, and thus I don't know what `@output` contains.

---

Please use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```